# WordPress, Events Calendar: Show a calendar as a widget, show all the upcoming events in list view

Tags: calendar, wordpress

I am using the plugin at https://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/. I would like to show the calendar as a widget on my sidebar. I would also like to show all the upcoming events in list view, on a different page. How can I accomplish the same?
I think the easiest way is through a shortcode but maybe there is another way.
Can you please help me? If there is another plugin that I should try then please let me know. 
Thank you so much!!